# Local extrema of a function, considering its $n-th$ derivative where $n$ might be odd or even.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

I found the following in my notes and need help to understand it.

Consider the following theorem:

"Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open, $f:A\to \mathbb R$. Suppose also that $f$ has all first order partial derivatives in $\bar x\in A°$, and has there a local extremum. Then follows that $grad(f(\bar x))=0"$

Then consider the following:

If we let $n=1$ in the above, it then follows that in the case that $f'(x)=0$ and $r$ is the smallest natural number such that $f^{(r)}(x)\neq 0$ it follows that if $r$ is $\mathbf {uneven}$ then $x$ is not a local extremum, and if $r$ is $\mathbf {even}$ and $f^{(r)}\ge0 $ (or $\le0$), so is $x$ the point of a local maximum (or minimum).

How is it that if $r$ is uneven there can be no local exremum? And that if $r$ is even then there will be one. How would I prove this from the theorem above?

Also, bearing in ming the above considered notions, how would one describe or show what would be the case for a saddle point?

Comment: What's your definition of the r-th derivative?  As far as I know when r=1 it is Jacobi and when r=2 it is Hesse, but I really don't know how to express the r-th derivative in a form independent of the infinitesimal when r is 3 or larger.

Comment: However, if A=R, then you can use Taylor series

Comment: @Vim well that's the thing. The only thing we can go on with regards to r is that it has to be the "best fitting", for want of a better term, in that the particular r would satisfy f^(r)(x)!=0.

Comment: I think the problem with considering what r could be, in the particular senses that you detailed above, is that the problem is for some general r. The main thing is, how would one show that for any function f, satisfying the above conditions, that we would be able to show that depending on r being even or odd, that there exists a local extremum at the point.

Comment: I'm still confused though. Whatever, if A is of more than one dimension, all the derivatives are not numbers.  Thus I don't even know what, say, f"(x)>0 means in your context.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry that I have overlooked n=1....  I have just posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take some hints from [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318078/191404). And please feel free to ask me for more details if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will give it a look!

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames You are welcome.